# using ng-switch with a controller variable

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use `ng-switch` on a controller variable and it's not working as expected or I am missing something. I'd like to switch on the `user_id` which is defined in the controller.

Here is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yj6nolWh4ByYBzhDu687?p=preview)

Controller

```
  $scope.user_id = "5";

  $scope.messages = [
    {id: 1, body: "Scope User Message", sent_messageable_id: 5},
    {id: 2, body: "Other Message", sent_messageable_id: 6}
  ]
```

HTML

```
  <div ng-repeat="message in messages">
    <div ng-switch on="message.sent_messageable_id">
      <div ng-switch-when="user_id">
        <!-- should be getting called but never does-->
        {{ message.body }}
      </div>
      <div ng-switch-default>
        {{ message.body }}
      </div>
      <div 
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your plunk is using a very old version of angularjs '1.0.5'.  Is that on purpose, or can you use a new version?

Comment: @lostintranslation not on purpose, I'm on 1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `ng-switch` in the wrong way. You have to be coherent with the expression that you use in the `ng-switch` initialization parameter. This is the correct way to use switch matching, standing to [AngularJS doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch).

```
<ANY ng-switch="expression">
  <ANY ng-switch-when="matchValue1">...</ANY>
  <ANY ng-switch-when="matchValue2">...</ANY>
  <ANY ng-switch-default>...</ANY>
</ANY>
```

Since `user_id` is not the expressione your exampole will not work.

I suggest you to use `ng-if`, that seems more suitable to your case (if I've understand what you want):

```
  <div ng-repeat="message in messages">
    <div>
      <div ng-if="user_id">
        <p>NOW getting called</p>
        {{ message.body }}
      </div>
      <div ng-if="!user_id">
        {{ message.body }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/0PupxymcXn2gj6s9JXgi?p=preview)